# Convert time series with 3-seconds update to time series with other interval

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I have a large file of measurements with 3-second period ([here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0bqVf9TmYwARTdKblhSZGtDQVk/edit?usp=sharing) is a small part of it). I made time serie:

```
library(zoo)
fmt<-"%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S"
dat <- read.zoo("~/Institut/Monitor/UA_test.csv",header=TRUE,
           dec=".",sep='\t',tz='',format=fmt,index=1)
```

On the next step I need convert it to the time series with 3 minutes update interval, where values must be the averages. What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Please provide your question in a reproducible form, i.e. with input.

Comment: I give a link to a file in the post: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0bqVf9TmYwARTdKblhSZGtDQVk/edit?usp=sharing. Can I do something yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `aggregate.zoo` :

```
aggregate(dat, as.POSIXct(cut(index(dat), "3 min")), mean)
```

Note that `dec="."` and `index=1` are used by default in `read.zoo` so they could be omitted from the `read.zoo` line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `period.apply` from the `xts` package

```
library(xts)
(x <- period.apply(dat, endpoints(dat, "minutes", 3), mean))
#                          UA       UB       UC
#2014-04-13 00:59:57 209.1605 226.4110 213.7115
#2014-04-13 01:02:57 215.4467 226.7065 211.3325
#2014-04-13 01:05:57 216.6252 225.4948 214.1290
#2014-04-13 01:07:45 218.4633 219.5589 214.1325
```

The second argument to `period.apply` is a vector of the row numbers of the end of each 3 minute period.  `endpoints(dat, "minutes", 3)` calculates that for you.

If you want the timestamps to be "rounded" instead of being the last timestamp of each period, you can use `align.time`, but `align.time` requires that the object is an `xts`, so you'd have to convert to `xts` first.

```
xx <- as.xts(x)
align.time(xx, n=60*3)
#                          UA       UB       UC
#2014-04-13 01:00:00 209.1605 226.4110 213.7115
#2014-04-13 01:03:00 215.4467 226.7065 211.3325
#2014-04-13 01:06:00 216.6252 225.4948 214.1290
#2014-04-13 01:09:00 218.4633 219.5589 214.1325
```

Comment: Thank you, align.time looks fine